# How do I round corners of myapp's icon

Tags: iphone, icons, rounding

In simulator mode, my app has an icon with round corners, but on a real iPhone, the corners aren't rounded.

Answer (score 5):

Corners get automatically rounded if you install via MobileInstallation (from iTunes, Xcode or App Store).
If you're building the package and installing it into /Applications manually or with cydia/apt, you have to make a rounded icon yourself.

You can find the images used to round the corners and add reflection in /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Other.artwork, the first 3 images are the mask, reflection and shadow. You can extract the .artwork file with [this script here](http://davepeck.org/software/iphoneart/)

Comment: @KiNG: Try archive.org for old links: http://web.archive.org/web/20081121061930/http://davepeck.org/software/iphoneart/

Answer (score 2):

by default the iPhone should round your corners and add a reflection effect.  Be sure you have not added the UIPrerenderedIcon key to your Info.plist file.  Hope this helps!

Adam

Comment: UIPrerenderedIcon is not in my Info.plist.

Comment: Unfortunately I would think that indicates your environment is not working as designed, but someone else here who knows something I don't may be able to provide additional insight.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is pretty old. New versions of iOS don't suffer from this problem unless you have Cydia installed and you're building your app as a .deb

If you want to round your corners for Cydia, do the following:

1. Download iFile and IconMaker from Cydia
2. Locate the icon file with iFile and click on it, then select IconMaker
3. Enable Save to Camera Roll
4. Generate icon
5. Email the generated icon(s) (144 and 77px versions) to yourself

Source: 
http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/how-to-make-apps-with-square-edges-into-smooth-round-edges.342846/